# Reliability of prepaids for foreign calls such as Lebara, Ortel... what to take into account?

Tags: germany, cellphones

There are many prepaid operators in Germany, that offer SIM cards for cheap foreign calls: Lebara, Ortel, Mobilka etc.

But I've heard bad opinions about their reliability and the connection quality. I've used Lebara, and honestly, I've had a lot of issues when calling, especially between 20 and 22. I've got a message 'Netz belegt', which would suggest, that the recipient was talking, but the number wasn't used.

However, it's hard to tell on the basis of a few usages is it a rule, or I was simply unlucky. So, when buying SIM card in Germany, what should I take into account? Are there any comparisons of reliability and quality of connections, especially in heavy traffic hours?

Comment: I think "Netz belegt" means "network overloaded", not "recipient already talking".

Comment: Not sure this is the answer you are looking for, but why not just use Skype? Depending on the destination it might be priced comparably and chances are its more reliable.

Comment: @OlegLevy but for skype you need internet, so you need reliable mobile card in first line.

Comment: I realize that. You will also need a smartphone and a MiFi router so you could get a data SIM card. It's just that I was using a similar setup on my recent trip to Italy and was able to get a 3G data card for 3Gb data for 15EUR and it worked great.

Comment: @OlegLevy, yes, Italy. Unfortunately, there's no united EU-wide cellular network. I'm disappointed by mobile internet offer in Germany...